# Laptop Lenovo Y570, bumblebee doesn't work?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a problem, I'm using ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Y570. There are a lot of materials for this question about linux and Nvidia GT555M video card, but still i'm new on linux and i can't handle it.
My bumblebee is installed but when I run "optirun --status" shows:
**umblebee status: Error (3.2.1): [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please**

when i type lscpi | grep VGA shows:
**00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 555M] (rev a1)**

also I get bumblebee indicator and its black, showing bumblebee is OFF.

I am scared of going throw this alone anymore, cause once i did it and my screen went black so i had many other problems to resolve and fix.
If anyone can explain me step by step what to do would be great, cause i'm really new.
Thanks!

Comment: Nobody can help me?